# .NET - Чем можно создавать\редактировать NLS файлы кодировок

Tags: c++, .net

Чем можно создавать\редактировать NLS файлы кодировок?

Comment: Редактором пробовали?

Comment: а каким? Я вот и ищу редактор.

Comment: тогда уточните в вопросе подробнее решаемую задачу. Чем подробнее опишите — тем больше шансов получить качественный ответ.

Comment: Необходимо сравнить 2 NLS  файла. То есть нужно открыть в редакторе 2 кодировки и сравнить их, посмотреть отличия. NLS файлы  бинарные, для их просмотра нужен специальный редактор. Чтобы сравнить два файла, нужно открыть их в редакторе и глазками найти отличия.